# How to addEventListener to table cells

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I'want to add an eventListener to the table cells so each time a table cell is clicked to execute a function .

```js
var getDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}



var calendar = {
    month: function () {
        var d = new Date();
        return d.getMonth() + this.nextMonth;
    },

    year: function () {
        var y = new Date();
        return y.getFullYear();
    },

    nextMonth: 1,
    
    cellColor: 'white',
    
}



var loopTable = function () {
    var daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(calendar.year(), calendar.month());
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var rows = table.rows;
    var l = 1;
    var month = calendar.month();
    var year = calendar.year();
    var firstDay = new Date(year + "-" + month).getDay();
    var currentDay = new Date().getDay();
    var dayOfMonth = new Date().getDate();

 
    for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

        if (rows[i] == rows[1]) {

            var k = 1;

            for (let j = firstDay; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {

                if (k === dayOfMonth && calendar.nextMonth === 1) {
                    rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = calendar.cellColor;
                

                }

                if (k <= daysInMonth) {
                    rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = k;
                    k++
                }

            }
        } else {
            for (let j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
                if (k === dayOfMonth && calendar.nextMonth === 1) {
                    rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor = calendar.cellColor;
                }
                if (k <= daysInMonth) {
                    rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = k;
                    k++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

loopTable();
clickCell();

function monthTitle() {

    var monthsArray = ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'Jun.', 'Jul.', 'Aug.', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.'];
    monthNum = calendar.month();
    var monthName = monthsArray[calendar.month() - 1] + '' + calendar.year();
    var title = document.getElementById('calendarTitle');
    var nextArrow = document.getElementById('nxt');
    var leftArrow = document.getElementById('prev');

  
    if (monthName === ('Dec.' + '' + calendar.year())){
        xmas();
    }
    if (monthNum >= 12) {
        nextArrow.className += ' inactiveLink';
    } else if (monthNum <= 1) {
        leftArrow.className += ' inactiveLink';
    } else {
        nextArrow.classList.remove('inactiveLink');
        leftArrow.classList.remove('inactiveLink');
    }

    title.innerHTML = '';
    var titleNode = document.createTextNode(monthName);
    title.appendChild(titleNode);


}
monthTitle();

function nextMonth() {
    clearTable();
    calendar.nextMonth += 1;
    monthTitle();
    loopTable();
}

function previousMonth() {
    clearTable();
    calendar.nextMonth -= 1;
    monthTitle();
    loopTable();
}

function clearTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var rows = table.rows;

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        cells = rows[i].cells;
        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
            if (cells[j].innerHTML = '') {
                cells[j].style.display = 'none';
            }
            cells[j].innerHTML = '';
            cells[j].style.backgroundColor = '#D9534F';
            cells[j].style.emptyCells = 'hide';
        }
    }
}

var next = document.getElementById('nxt');
var previous = document.getElementById('prev');
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var cell = table.rows;
next.addEventListener('click', nextMonth);
previous.addEventListener('click', previousMonth);



function clickCell() {
    var row = document.getElementById('myTable').rows;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < row[i].cells.length; j++ ) {
       
            row[i].cells[j].addEventListener('click', function(){
       console.log('click');
            })
        }
    }
}
clickCell();
```

```css
body {
            background-color: rgb(0, 121, 191);
        }
        
        table {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #D9534F;
            border: 1px solid white;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 25px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
        }
        
        td {
            border: 1px solid white;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
        th {
            height: 50px;
        }
        
        .calArrows {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 35px;
        }
        
        #nxt {
            font-size: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 25%
        }
        
        #prev {
            font-size: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 25%;
        }
        
        #calendarTitle {
            font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 25px;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .inactiveLink {
            cursor: not-allowed;
            pointer-events: none;
             
        }
        
        #myTable {
            empty-cells: hide;
        }
        
        .xmasDec {
            width: 90%;
            height: 70%;
            position: absolute;
            top: -10%;
            left: 5%;
        }
        
        #calWraper {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #myCan {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 10%;
            width: 90%;
            height: 70%;
            opacity: 0, 5;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas class="myCan" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <div id="calWraper">
        <table id="myTable">
            <caption id="calendarTitle">Test</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thur</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <canvas id="myCan" width="200" height="200" style="background-color: transparent"></canvas>
            <a href="#" id="prev" class="calArrows"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" ></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="nxt" class="calArrows"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" ></i></a>



    </div>



</html>
```

I tried by creating a function that it will loop through rows and cells and add the eventListener to each  . But it seems that its not working , its working on random instances which is really strange behavior . Here is the function i create:

```
function clickCell() {
    var row = document.getElementById('myTable').rows;
 for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < row[i].cells.length; j++ ) {
                    console.log(row[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
            row[i].cells[j].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    console.log('click');
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't look all that minimal. Can't you reduce it a bit?

Comment: Am I the only one who can't see a thing because of the console there?

Comment: @Shinratensei: Use the "Full page" link.

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, attach *one* event handler to the table itself, and use `event.target` to find out which cell was clicked.

Comment: i should add an event listener to the table and use e.target to target cells ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems your canvas is overlapping your table. Because of that `td` elements in your table are never clicked.

You will need to add CSS property `pointer-events:none` to your canvas.

```
#myCan {
    ...
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This way it won't block table from being clicked anymore.

You can also add event listeners to your cells way simpler:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
    console.log("clicked")
}));
```

That creates a separate function for each cell; instead, you could share one function without losing any functionality:

```
function clickHandler() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
    console.log("clicked")
}
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
```

---

Some browsers still don't have `forEach` on the HTMLCollection returned by `querySelectorAll`, but it's easily polyfilled:

```
if (!HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLCollection.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}
```

If you have to support truly obsolete browsers that don't have `Array.prototype.forEach`, see [the polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Yes sir you are right, canvas was overlapping the table and couldnt let me click the cells.

Comment: I've added a note about `forEach`. You should also change the example to **not** use an arrow function for the event handler, since using `this` within that handler (to refer to the clicked td) is likely to be important. But I didn't change that bit, didn't want to do too much.

Comment: @ChristodoulouAndreas: You're entirely free to accept any answer you like, of course, but wasn't the real issue here the canvas issue addressed above, rather than the event hookup issue addressed by my answer? If so, you might consider switching the accepted answer over to this one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder basically  i was looking a general answer about looping through table cells(whats the prefer way to do it)  and secondly to solve my problem which i couldnt click on the first cell rows.

Comment: @ChristodoulouAndreas: Cool. FWIW, I've edited the end of the above a bit; no need to create separate functions for each cell.

Answer (score 9):

This is a case for *event delegation*: Hook the click event on the table (or table body), not individual cells, and then determine which cell was clicked by looking at `event.target` and its ancestors.

Simplified example:

```
document.querySelector("#my-table tbody").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var td = event.target;
  while (td !== this && !td.matches("td")) {
      td = td.parentNode;
  }
  if (td === this) {
      console.log("No table cell found");
  } else {
      console.log(td.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

Live Copy:

```js
document.querySelector("#my-table tbody").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var td = event.target;
  while (td !== this && !td.matches("td")) {
      td = td.parentNode;
  }
  if (td === this) {
      console.log("No table cell found");
  } else {
      console.log(td.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>Bloggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Muhammad</td>
      <td>Abdul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maria</td>
      <td>Gonzales</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that instead of the loop you could use the new (experimental) [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method on elements:

```
var td = event.target.closest("td");
```

...but A) It's still experimental, and B) It won't stop when it reaches the `tbody`, so in theory if you had nested tables, would find the wrong cell.

If you need to support browsers that don't have [`Element.prototype.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), in this specific case you could use `td.tagName !== "TD"` instead of `!td.matches("td")` (note the capitalization).

Comment: Could you explain why this is better than adding a click listener to each cell?

Comment: @dgrogan: Primarily it's useful when you're adding and removing elements, but relative to the OP's code it's useful because we create only **one** event handler function instead of dozens, hundreds, or thousands. But that issue could be solved without using event delegation (define the function once, hook it up dozens, hundreds, or thousands of times). But it still fewer event registrations to do and keep track of...

Answer (score 1):

**Using only the DOM objects**

> Here's an example cell wise event listener added on an HTML table (TicTacToe). It can be achieved easily using 'this' keyword and 'querySelectorAll'

The logic is in the JavaScript file:

1. First, get all the cells by their 'tag' ("td") using 'querySelectorAll' and save it as a list
2. Add an event listener to each of the cells, and give a function name to do whatever you want
3. Inside the event listener function, using this keyword update the cell content, or call other functions or do whatever task you have to complete.

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td");

for (var cell of cells) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', marker)
}

function marker() {
  if (this.textContent === 'X') {
    this.innerHTML = "O";
  } else if (this.textContent === 'O') {
    this.innerHTML = " ";
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = "X";
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="ticTac">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
        <td>. </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```