# HTML eventlistener on each row of table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the problem:

- I have a table with rows that have keypress listeners
- Each row is contentEditable
- I want to make the wrapping tbody element contentEditable (to allow selecting multiple rows by click and dragging)
- If I do make tbody contentEditable the keypress event is no longer
  triggered in the rows

  - only the tbody element recieves the event

The main issue is that setting tbody as editable obscures the keypress events for the table rows

EDIT:
Is there any form of pointer-events:none for keyboard events?

How can I have the rows still recieve the event or how can I enable drag and select without making tbody/table contentEditable?

Would appreciate any feedback or help, thanks!

---

Here is an example code snippet if the description is unclear:

```html
<style>
    table{
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    table, th,td, tr{
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    tr,td, th {
      padding: 3px;
      text-align: left;
      height: 2em;
    }
    
</style>

<div>
<table>
  <thead style = "background-color:white">
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody> <!-- need to make this tbody contenteditable -->
    <tr contenteditable = 'true' onkeypress='keyPressed(event)'>
        <td>v1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable = 'true' onkeypress='keyPressed(event)'>
        <td>v2</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>
    function keyPressed(){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
          event.preventDefault();
          row = event.target;
          row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',"<tr contenteditable = 'true' onkeypress='keyPressed(event)'><td></td></tr>");
          row.nextSibling.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to addEventListener to table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341171/how-to-addeventlistener-to-table-cells)

Comment: Using tables for this seems like the wrong approach, why not have them as simply divs that can be dragged?

Comment: @imvain2 I think your right, divs are a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelectorAll('contenteditable td')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
    console.log("clicked")
}));
```

[lear more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341171/how-to-addeventlistener-to-table-cells)

Comment: This doesn't work, if the overarching tbody is set as contenteditable, it still obscures the row keypress events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.target` to see which element is actually being click on. For example, in my snippet `tbody` and the `tr` has `contenteditable` but as you can see in the console, `element.target` and `element.currentTarget` both retrieve a different field so you know you can use it that way.

But I would probably just recommend using divs instead, as they will be easier to work with.

```js
document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').addEventListener("click", function(el) {
   console.log(el.target,el.currentTarget)
});
/*
    function keyPressed() {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        row = event.target;
        row.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<tr contenteditable = 'true' onkeypress='keyPressed(event)'><td></td></tr>");
        row.nextSibling.focus();
      }
    }*/
```

```css
table {
  background-color: cyan;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr,
td,
th {
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead style="background-color:white">
      <tr>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody contenteditable='true'>
      <!-- need to make this tbody contenteditable -->
      <tr contenteditable='true'>
        <td>v1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr contenteditable='true'>
        <td>v2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for switching the event type to 'keypress', the tbody is both the currentTarget and target (unlike with click event interestingly).  I will be switching to div most likely, however, I'd love to figure this out for knowing's sake.