# Change inner txt of table

Tags: javascript

I have a table with names, surnames and etc. I should change the value of the clicked td using input. I managed to changed the value of the first td but I am not sure how can change the values of specific td.

Here is my code.

```js
let inp
let changevalue
let click = addEventListener("focus" ,function(){
    changevalue = document.querySelector("td")
  inp = document.createElement("input")
  inp.value = changevalue.innerHTML
  changevalue.innerHTML = " "
    changevalue.append(inp)
})
let newclick = addEventListener("blur" , function(){
    changevalue.innerHTML = inp.value
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%" id = "TB">
  <tr >
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341171/how-to-addeventlistener-to-table-cells

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event listeners on each `td` element and use the blur event only for the dynamically created `input`.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("#TB td");
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.addEventListener("click", e=>{
     let inp = document.createElement("input")
     inp.value = td.innerHTML
     td.innerHTML = " "
     td.append(inp);
     inp.focus();
     inp.addEventListener("blur", e=>{
        td.innerHTML = inp.value;
     });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%" id = "TB">
  <tr >
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway that I can use this method to add input?

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean choose the td by using ‘ this ‘ method

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan If you use `function(e)` instead, you can use `this` to refer to the `td`.