# How best can I write this line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
$("table).on("input",":selected", "td" , function ()
```

Comment: That *is* JavaScript. Do you mean how to achieve the same behavior without jQuery (assuming this is jQuery)?

Comment: This isn't proper usage of jQuery `on` method. I can only assume you meant 3 different selectors as the first string param, then a callback.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341171/how-to-addeventlistener-to-table-cells  Does this help?

Comment: `input` event on a table cell? I think there's no such thing